# Find from which library the class comes from in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, jar

Lets say I have a import line in my class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

How can I know from which library does it come from? Lets say I have maven folder, that contains tons of libraries.

**Why?**
I want to use this class/library in my other project, but I don't know which JAR to copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open type (Ctrl-Shift-T) enter `org.apache.log4j.Logger`, and you'll see which jar it belongs to (in gray).

Comment: Also, make sure you Link with Editor (the double arrows in the package explorer view) so you're taken to the actual file when you click on it.

Comment: Or place the cursor on "Logger" in your source and press F3.